# Visual Studio Code HTML Format doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code (ver. 1.12.0) Format Document seems not to work.
I tried with shortcut, with context menu but the result is always the same.
For example I have this line:

```
<div class="form-group">    <label for="comment">   </label>   <textarea name="" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control">   </textarea></div>
```

the result is simply this:

```
<div class="form-group"> <label for="comment">   </label> <textarea name="" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control">   </textarea></div>
```

It only removes some space before the label element!